# Numpy compute dot product of the inner array of a 3D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, dot-product, numpy-einsum

I have two arrays that look as follows:

[image]

In code that is:

```
t = np.random.rand(6, 6, 2)
```

I now want to compute the dot product of the axis 2 arrays (the ones of shape 2), for each of the entries of the axis 0 and 1 arrays.

I can do it with a for loop:

```
Q = np.zeros_like(t)
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        Q[i,j] = t[i,j].dot(t[i,j])
```

### How can I do this with numpy functions?

I could not get it to work with `.dot`, `.tensordot` or similar methods...

`t.dot(t)` produces this error `ValueError: shapes (6,6,2) and (6,6,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 2) != 6 (dim 1)` which is to be expected, however I would like to circumvent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're taking the `dot` product of all rows with themselves, you can simplify to a multiplication of `t` with itself and adding the result. In order to have the same shape as `t`, you can use `np.broadcast_to`:

```
np.broadcast_to((t*t).sum(-1)[...,None], t.shape)
```

---

**Update**

Based on the comments, it appears that you just need:

```
(t*t).sum(-1)
```

---

Check:

```
np.allclose(Q, np.broadcast_to((t*t).sum(-1)[...,None], t.shape))
# True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I got it working with an, in my opinion, easier approach. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: Your approach produces a different result to `Q`, which I assumed to be the expected output. Meaning that my answer can be simplified to `(t*t).sum(-1)`, which seems quite a simple approach IMO @charel-f

Comment: Oh I see, I must have messed up my arrays since I was using a different array while doing the exercise then the one used to ask my question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum("...i, ...i", t, t)
```

which produces the same output as my for loop.